# Which SMD component is labeled "20 3C"?

Tags: identification, surface-mount

[image]

Please help me to identify the SMD marked as `20 3C`, which is used in a cable TV set top box tuner section for amplifying the RF input. It's operating on 5V DC. Please inform me of the package code, and the component value. It resembles the SOT89 dimensions.

Comment: 0
down vote
 

If it is SOT-89 Maybe a voltage regulator, MC78LC33HT1 or RH5RL33AA (3.3V). What is the designation letter? (the complete thing under R167).

Comment: @Antonio I take it all back completely. [This older version datasheet](http://lib.chipdip.ru/204/doc000204638.pdf) confirms that the MC78LC33HT1 does have the marking 3C along with a 2 digit year code, but not arranged in a square.

Comment: @TomCarpenter,  also [this new](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/MC78LC00-D.PDF).  But marking suggest me that  is more likely your XC6203E432PR.

Comment: @Antonio that new one indicates there are 5 letters and a dot in one of two places, which doesn't match.

Comment: Never mind, not the XC6203E432PR, the markings don't work out (it would mean a 1-3V regulator that is 4.3V).

Comment: A voltage regulator in an RF path? What.

Answer (score 1):

If it is SOT-89 maybe a MC78LC33HT1 3.3V voltage regulator (or RH5RL33AA).
You can see the marking code in [this old datasheet](http://lib.chipdip.ru/204/doc000204638.pdf), page 11.

Comment: when i searched in web i found the component which is femilier with my circuit please check the attachment give your suggestion, because it is used in RF section of set top box.[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://www.triquint.com/products/d/DOC-A-00000398

Comment: I don't think that it's your component, but if you tell us the letter before "195", in your picture this could help to identify.

Comment: it is marked as R195